# How to fix not receiving kafka messages in python but receiving the same messages in shell?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want to consume messages coming in a kafka topic. I am using debezium which oplogs the mongodb changes and puts them in the kafka queue. I am able to connect to kafka using my python code, list the kafka topics. Although, when I want to consume the messages, its all blank whereas the same topic when consumed from the shell gives messages, performs perfectly.

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

topic = "dbserver1.inventory.customers"
# consumer = KafkaConsumer(topic, bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092', auto_offset_reset='earliest', auto_commit_enable=True)
consumer = KafkaConsumer(topic)
print("Consumer connected!")
# print("Topics are {}".format(consumer.topics()))
for message in consumer:
    print(message)
```

Comment: Were you using `bootstrap_servers` option when you are trying to consume?

Comment: yes as written above

Comment: can you share the debezium connector configuration?

Comment: Are the consumers in the same consumer-group? If so, that's expected I guess.